# PosPrinter for .net Printing only once and Hangs

Tags: c#, posprinter

I am building winforms .net Application , I have a E-Pos printer on Network , 
using this Code below :
On Form Loading Printer initializing :

```
    explorer = new PosExplorer(this);
        DeviceInfo receiptPrinterDevice = explorer.GetDevice("PosPrinter", Properties.Settings.Default.KitchenPrinter); //May need to change this if you don't use a logicial name or use a different one.
        kitchenPrinter = (PosPrinter)explorer.CreateInstance(receiptPrinterDevice);
       ConnectToPrinter();


    private void ConnectToPrinter()
    {  
        kitchenPrinter.Open();
        kitchenPrinter.Claim(10000);
        kitchenPrinter.DeviceEnabled = true;
     }
```

Function Call on Print Button :

```
 private void PrintReceipt()
    {

         try
            {  kitchenPrinter.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, "test");
              }
            finally
            {

            }
    }
```

When I want to Switch to Other Form I call Disconnect Function

```
        DisconnectFromPrinter(kitchenPrinter);
        Reporting frm = new Reporting(curuser);
        frm.Show();
        this.Hide();


  private void DisconnectFromPrinter(PosPrinter kitchenPrinter)
    {

        try
        {
           kitchenPrinter.Release();
            kitchenPrinter.Close();
        }
       catch { }
    }
```

It prints successful one time ,when pressing to print next time it throws and exception
**Method ClaimDevice threw an exception.  Attempt was made to perform an illegal or unsupported operation with the device, or an invalid parameter value was used.**

any suggestion ?

Comment: could you retry without the `DeviceEnabled = false` assignment? related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430995/cant-claim-the-posprinter; doc https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ec9736fb-42ff-4477-9dbd-e3af83fd14db/what-is-proper-way-of-using-posprinter?forum=posfordotnet (devices may be shareable)

Comment: [release implies disable. close implies release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd161612(v=winembedded.10).aspx). code seems to be correct, may be a driver/device problem.

Comment: i try to open ,claim, enable in form loading out side my button click and printing many times on button click and releasing it when switchin to other form. but once i come back to my form it hangs again. so it seems that releasing function is not working good??

Comment: yes that may be. unfortunately `Release` is void... no info about success of the operation. "hang" = exception mentioned in your post? could you update the code so we see the big picture, including form/button interaction?

Comment: hang yes means the above mentioned exception.. question been edited

Comment: attach a debugger and prove that `ConnectToPrinter` is called after `DisconnectFromPrinter` and before subsequent `PrintReceipt`

Comment: yes i have checked and been called propably. do you think its about claim (10000) parameter value ?

Comment: You'll have to call CreateInstance() again.  Calling Close() was a bad idea, just don't do that.  If you want to print from other forms as well then simply declare kitchenPrinter static.

Comment: since form is loading that means the new instance is created .what you are telling have no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Release command is not being effective and may Claim command is throwing an error every time I am loading my form because it is being Claimed before.

So I have Create a separate Class Called "createPOS"

```
         class createPOS
{
 public  static PosExplorer explorer;
  public  static PosPrinter kitchenPrinter;
  public static void createPos()
  {
      explorer = new PosExplorer();
      DeviceInfo receiptPrinterDevice = explorer.GetDevice("PosPrinter", Properties.Settings.Default.KitchenPrinter); //May need to change this if you don't use a logicial name or use a different one.
      kitchenPrinter = (PosPrinter)explorer.CreateInstance(receiptPrinterDevice);
      kitchenPrinter.Open();
      kitchenPrinter.Claim(10000);
      kitchenPrinter.DeviceEnabled = true;
  }
      public static void Print(string text){
          if (kitchenPrinter.Claimed)
              PrintTextLine(kitchenPrinter, text);  // kitchenPrinter.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, text ); //Print text, then a new line character.
       }
      private static void PrintTextLine(PosPrinter printer, string text)
      {
          if (text.Length < printer.RecLineChars)
              printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, text + Environment.NewLine); //Print text, then a new line character.
          else if (text.Length > printer.RecLineChars)
              printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, TruncateAt(text, printer.RecLineChars)); //Print exactly as many characters as the printer allows, truncating the rest, no new line character (printer will probably auto-feed for us)
          else if (text.Length == printer.RecLineChars)
              printer.PrintNormal(PrinterStation.Receipt, text + Environment.NewLine); //Print text, no new line character, printer will probably auto-feed for us.
      }
      private static string TruncateAt(string text, int maxWidth)
      {
          string retVal = text;
          if (text.Length > maxWidth)
              retVal = text.Substring(0, maxWidth);

          return retVal;
      }
  }
```

and On the Login form that it will only be accessed once I have initialized my  printer

```
     createPOS.createPos();
```

and on MainForm I have called the Printing Method :

```
        createPOS.Print("This allows me to Print Several times");
```

on that way I am able to print several times and even I navigate to other forms and come back that works fine.

Thank you guys.

Comment: What documentation or project did you follow to achieve this code? I am unsure whether you are supposed to claim the device each time you are going to use it, or the whole livetime of the app. I always get an exception when I do claim.