# Error communication with Epson FP-81 II (fiscal printer)

Tags: c#, epson, pos-for-.net

When I download driver they proporcionate backend code. When execute, the method `claim()` return error 106.

```
// Console.WriteLine("Initializing PosExplorer ");
posExplorer = new PosExplorer();

// Console.WriteLine("Taking FiscalPrinter device ");
DeviceInfo fp = posExplorer.GetDevice("FiscalPrinter", "FiscalPrinter1");

// Console.WriteLine("Creating instance of FiscalPrinter device ");
posCommonFP = (PosCommon)posExplorer.CreateInstance(fp);
posCommonFP.StatusUpdateEvent += new StatusUpdateEventHandler(co_OnStatusUpdateEvent);

// Console.WriteLine("Initializing FiscalPrinter ");
FiscalPrinter fiscalprinter = (FiscalPrinter) posCommonFP;

Console.WriteLine("Performing Open() method ");
fiscalprinter.Open();

Console.WriteLine("Performing Claim() method ");
fiscalprinter.Claim(1000); // Exception
```

Message error:

> ErrorCode: Illegal
>   ErrorCodeExtended: 10002
>   Message: Stub message. LockPort Error. IORet = 4

[Question relationed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430995/cant-claim-the-posprinter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is neccesarry change port to 9100 for model printer FP-81 II.
Supported by EPSON.

[image: NPort configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the port name setting by Epson.opos.tm.setpos.exe/SetupPOS.exe etc. is correct.

---

**ErrorCodeExtended: 10002** will be below.
It is described in "C:\Program Files (x86)\OPOS\Epson2\Include\epson.h".

```
const LONG EPSNERREXT = 10000; // EPSON specific error base
const LONG OPOS_EX_BADPORT = 2 + EPSNERREXT; // invalid Port
```

It is described in "C:\Program Files\epson\OPOS for.NET\Documentation\OPOS Error Code.pdf"

```
Error Code  Extended Error Code
Illegal     EX_BADPORT
"The port name is illegal."
```

---

**Message: Stub message.LockPort Error.IORet = 4** may be internal to EPSON.

Comment: I can't find this files. My instalation was be on "C:\Program Files\EPSON\UPOSDriverForFiscal\OPOS.NET\SetupPOS". Can you write complete path where a must change values?

Comment: FiscalPrinter should be closely related to the target country, but I do not live in that country, so I can not know the exact path name. If you have a PC installed in your developer mode of OPOS ADK for .NET, you should find various guide documents and tools in it, so search for it. If you still do not know, please contact EPSON support.

Comment: EPSON support team tell me that valid port is 9100 when I was configuren on NPort aplication as 4001, 903 and 80.

Comment: Is it the printer's own settings? Instead, it is important what is the target device name and connection port information indicated by the (logical?) device name "FiscalPrinter1" device information definition of POS for.NET on the PC/POS where the POS application runs.

Comment: The settings are from another device called [NPort](https://www.moxa.com/en/products/industrial-edge-connectivity/serial-device-servers/general-device-servers/nport-5100-series). When NPort is configurated its possible to do test with SetupPOS that is installed with drivers for Epson printer. In my case for model FP-81 II is [here](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=6113&pcat=51&pid=3318).

Comment: For example, such [tools](https://partner.epson.jp/support/small_printer/develop/tool.htm) and [FAQ](https://faq2.epson.jp/web/Detail.aspx?id=32827) are introduced in Japan. Please contact EPSON Support for the equivalent English tools and materials.